# Cant start new activity from onActivityResult method in main activity

Tags: android, bitmap, onactivityresult

I have used following method to get image after calling photo gallery intent. I want to start another activity by passing the bitmap of that image and show that image in the second activity. But, nothing will happen after a photo is picked from photo gallery.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent
                    data) {
        final String path;

        if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

        Uri imageFileUri = data.getData();

            if (imageFileUri != null) {
                try {
                path = getPath(imageFileUri);
                BitmapFactory.Options load_option = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                load_option.inPurgeable = true;
                load_option.inDensity = 0;
                load_option.inTargetDensity = 0;
                load_option.inDensity = 0;
                load_option.inScaled = false;
                bmp_main = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, load_option);
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bmp_main.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

                Intent intentPhoto = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                intentPhoto.putExtra("image",byteArray);
                startActivity(intentPhoto);

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            }


        }
```

Can anybody tell what's the problem?

**N.B.: 1.I have added the activity in the manifest**

**2. There is no logcat error or exception regarding this**

**3. I have done debugging, it goes upto startActivity line correctly, but after that nothing happen**

Comment: Are you sure you're going into your if condition? Try to log the imageFileUri value.

Comment: The code seems fine, putting some log statements in there might help you further.

Comment: Indenting the code better will make it much easier to read and find the bug.

Comment: are you getting your imagepath correctly??

Comment: @PiyushGupta, yes I got it correctly as far I understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code...

```
    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK
            && null != data) {
        Uri contentUri = data.getData();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, ViewGallery_Photo.class)
                .setData(contentUri));
    }
```

So in onActivityResult there are 2 logic

1) if you are loading images from gallery then it will take you to other activity

2) if you are capturing image from camera then it will take you to other activity not the same activity which is calling by gallery ...

Comment: Could you please do something using my codes, What I want is that there is a photoButton, clicking which PhotoGallery will open. And when I select any photo, it will be viewed in another activity. Hope you are clear about my question now...

Comment: I have updated my answer, you just add this condition inside your onActivityReslut and instead of ViewGallery_Photo.class write your Activity.class.. and you are done with what you want...

Comment: Then please tell me how to retrieve the contentUri from the second activity and convert it into bitmap

Comment: But first of all tell me weather this worked or not.. With this code are you able to move to next activity or not???

Comment: Ok, so in second activity just take one image-view and get the stored image which you are saving from this activity by path. And if this answer helps then please accept the answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43598/discussion-between-crazylearner-and-innocent-killer)

Comment: I have almost completed my task, but still facing a little problem. When the picked image is appeared in an imageView in the second activity, it will be rotated sometimes (when the original image's height is greater than width), how to get rid of this automatic rotating?

Answer (score 1):

Call this out of your ***if*** condition:

```
Intent intentPhoto = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intentPhoto.putExtra("image",byteArray);
startActivity(intentPhoto);
```

Try this:

```
         try {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            String fullPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .getAbsolutePath();
            try {

                File dir = new File(fullPath);
                if (!dir.exists()) {
                    dir.mkdirs();
                }
                OutputStream fOut = null;
                File file = new File(fullPath, "userImage" + ".png");
                if (file.exists())
                    file.delete();
                file.createNewFile();
                fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                fOut.flush();
                fOut.close();
                Log.v("Image saved", "in" + file);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("saveToExternalStorage()", e.getMessage());
            }

            decodeFile(picturePath);
            /*
             * iv_display.setImageBitmap(mPhoto); Bitmap useThisBitmap =
             * Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mPhoto, mPhoto.getWidth(),
             * mPhoto.getHeight(), true);
             */

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
            bytepicture = baos.toByteArray();

            Intent newdata = new Intent(MainMenu.this, SecondActivity.class);
            newdata.putExtra("picture", bytepicture);
            startActivity(newdata);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.v("TAG", "No Image Selected:");
        }
```

***For decode file :***

```
 public void decodeFile(String filePath) {

    // Decode image size
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o);

    // The new size we want to scale to
    final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 1024;

    // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
    int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
    int scale = 3;
    while (true) {
        if (width_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE && height_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE)
            break;
        width_tmp /= 2;
        height_tmp /= 2;
        scale *= 2;
    }

    // Decode with inSampleSize
    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o2.inSampleSize = scale;
    mPhoto = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o2);
    myBitmap = ExifUtils.rotateBitmap(filePath, mPhoto);

    // image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

Comment: outside the if condition, How can I get byteArray?